# Kotlin Singleton vs Java Singleton

Tags: kotlin

My Question is what is the difference between these two:

```
@Volatile private var INSTANCE: SomeClass? = null

fun getInstance(someValue: SomeType): SomeClass{
    return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
        INSTANCE ?: SomeClass(someValue).also { INSTANCE = it }
    }
}
```

and

```
object SomeClass {
    ....
}
```

Comment: @BoristheSpider sorry for asking a stupid question but literally would want to learn. I got no one to ask, can you elaborate on that please? :(

Comment: The real question is why do you need a singleton? It's a commonly recognised anti-pattern that makes code inextensible and untestable.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Stateless singletons are still sensible. In this case they're usually best written as enums in Java, though.

Comment: This is more of a curiosity question. I am trying to learn proper android programming by looking at an app called "Plaid" (https://github.com/nickbutcher/plaid/blob/master/core/src/main/java/io/plaidapp/core/designernews/data/comments/CommentsRepository.kt) In here they create all the "Repository" and "DataSource" classes as a Singleton. Now that I think about it again, my question should have been why those classes are made to have single instance.

Comment: @chrylis not convinced. It's impossible to mock a singleton out for testing as you've baked the DI strategy into the code. Even with a stateless singleton, it will have logic; and you've just made the dependant class untestable. If the singleton contains only constants then that may be workable; but as soon as you need different values between prod/dev/test you've again shot yourself in the foot.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Enums can implement interfaces.

Comment: @chrylis I'm well aware. What's your point? All of what I said above holds - using an `enum` is an implementation detail.

Comment: I think what you guys are talking about is too advance for me, do you have any article I could read to understand all you guys are talking about? :(

Comment: @BoristheSpider MockK can mock Kotlin objects, i.e. singletons, so no problem there.

Comment: @ArchieG.Quiñones I see one clear difference between the two code snippets, one being that the first `SomeClass` constructor requires a parameter (`someValue`) and that the second doesn't depend on parameters. Because that constructor doesn't exist in the first snippet, this code won't compile.

Comment: I also think that the example you link to, the Plaid app with its singleton implementations through `@Volatile private var INSTANCE: X? = null` is a bad idea given that Kotlin has the very simple, understandable and idiomatic `object X`.